# Weird characters as response data on axios post request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js

The issue I am facing here is that the file which gets downloaded on clicking the submitUser() method is blank. I checked the network tab in the browser the preview shows weird characters as showing in the image.

[image: weird characters]

Then I added the debugger in the response in submitUser method, the response data coming from the controller is weird characters.

Please help me resolve this problem.

```
<template>
 <v-btn @click.prevent='submitUser'>Save</v-btn>
</template>



<script>
    export default {
     methods: {
      submitUser() {
       var url = '/sign.json',
       fileName = "Profile.pdf",
       file;
       this.$axios.post(url, { user: this.user, responseType: 'blob' })
       .then(response => {
         file = new Blob(
           [response.data],
           { type: 'application/pdf' }
         );
         FileSaver.saveAs(file, fileName);
         });
      }
     }
</script>
```

users_controller.rb

```
   def user_profile
      @user = current_user

      file = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
        render_to_string(template: 'user/profile.pdf.erb', locals: { user: @user })
      )
      send_data(file, filename: "file_name.pdf", type: 'application/pdf')
   end
```

profile.pdf.erb

```
<b>User Details</b><br /><br />
<%= user.name %><br />
<%= user.first_name %><br />
<%= user.address %><br />
```

routes.rb

```
post 'sign', to: 'users#user_profile', constraints: ->(req) { req.format == :json }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `response` be a `Blob`? Get rid of the `file = new Blob..` and `FileSaver.saveAs(response, fileName);`

Comment: I tried what you suggest. This is the error I got.
Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL'